# Randint won't execute

Tags: python, random

Why does this error pop at the first line:

> NameError: name 'random' is not defined

```
correctPath = random.randint(1,2,3)

if chosenPath == str(correctPath):
   print("Thank you for your help")
   print("this has been altered for creative purposes")
elif chosenPath != str(correctPath):
    print("Thanks in advance.")
else:
   print ("code to be written")
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Note that your `else` statement here will never be reached.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I am new to the website. However, I would like to clarify that the first line of code is where the problem seems to be although I cannot solve why. It identifies that there are 4 paths instead of 3 in the program.

Comment: `randint` only takes two arguments doesn't it? Did you mean to use `sample`/`choice`? And if you get an error, post the exact, full error in the question and format it as code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am very new to coding. The syntax error appears as follows:

Comment: And ya, the problem is that `randint` only takes 2 arguments. What was your intent for passing 3? I think you want `random.choice([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: The aim was to have 3 paths that could be followed in the text-based game I was programming, but using choice seems to be the sensible option here. Thank you very much for the advice. One last question, however. If the else statement can never be reached, is there a way to have a third path in the program in another way?

Comment: @Phoebe What 3 possibilities are there though? The user can either pick the same as `correct_path`, (the first branch), or they can pick the wrong path (the second branch). What would you want to lead to a third branch?

Comment: One path in the game would allow the player to advance to the next level, another would lose them points and the final one would end the game. If it seems unnecessary I assume it would be fine to simply exclude the third possibility.

Comment: If it is necessary or not is up to you I guess. How would you decide if it's the third option? Is that just a 33% chance? (e.g. correctPath = 1, choosing 2 would then lose you points and 3 would end the game?)

Comment: Yes, that was the goal although I am researching other ways I can write the code so that the paths can lead to perhaps another level of the game.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. As I can see from my review, my question appears to be poorly constructed. In the future, I will refrain from using this helpful website for code review. This has helped me understand how to use randint appropriately in a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
random.randint(a,b)
```

function returns a random **integer** *N* such that *a<=N<=b*. This means that you can use only **two arguments** while your third argument is needless.

Comment: Thank you. So does that mean that a third option can only be generated through the use of the function "choice"? I have one final question as well. If the else statement is never met, is there any other way I can program it so that the program has two paths that can be chosen at random if the correctPath != str(chosenPath)?